# jquery 1.5.1 Input syntax error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I was using jquery 1.4.4.min the following script worked.

```
$(":INPUT").change( function(){dataChanged=true; $(this).addClass("box2");});
```

I had to change to jquery 1.5.1.min and now I am geting this error

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: INPUT

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work with `$(":input")`?  I think the selectors are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$(':input')` or `$('input')`